# Apache2 not serving php scripts

Tags: php, apache2

I have searched the web for days now, taking what I have found and applying it to my configuration and still cannot work with php on my local machine.  I am at a total loss and frustrated to say the least!

Running on Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit and pretty sure that Ive went over all configuration files that otherwise need to be edited in order to get php configured, I'm at a stand still!  The following are my Apache2 files.

**apache2.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
identification number when it starts.
This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
Timeout 300

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off

<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
   Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

And,
   **dir.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
 Directory Index index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I keep reading references to the **httpd.conf** file however this file does not exist. Am I suppose to manually create my own following an installation?

All I get is the following error when navigating to http://localhost/

```
**Error**
Not found: vhost: localhost
```

In the past I never bothered creating separate sites/vhosts. All I am interested in is getting php served up when navigating to my /var/www/html directory.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!@

Comment: Which packages did you install?

Comment: Well the one that has been referred to above all is **lib-apache2-mod-php7.2** which is installed`and enabled.  I can go look over it all again and list all installed modules etc.. if its neccessary. My apologies for leaving this out.

Comment: That's ok, I was wondering if you had `lib-apache2-mod-php7.2` installed. For me it was just installing Apache2, PHP & lib-apache2-mod-php and everything worked "out of the box" IIRC. I might get back to you once I'm @home.

Comment: Thank you kerbholz and yes,all of my installations in the past worked flawlessly out of the box.  I'm dumbfounded as to what the issue is as all files that Im at least aware of that require some input to enable php are good to go.

Comment: It just occurred to me and may be some clue to a fix that while apache2 on my machine is not serving up my php scripts, my browser is not attempting to download them as files.  This has always been the case in the past.